# How to efficiently convert a multidimensional collection of 2 different types into a multidimensional List

Tags: java, arrays, performance, collections, set

I have the following HashSet, which needs to have TreeSets as elements :

```
HashSet<TreeSet<Integer>> hash=new HashSet<TreeSet<Integer>>();
```

I want to be able to store ordered elements into the TreeSet, order is also important hence the choice of a TreeSet. Those elements themselves need to be ordered but not necessarily sorted. But I must return :

```
List<List<Integer>>
```

What is the most efficient way to convert my **hash** into a List of a List of Integers in terms of performance ?

Thank you

Comment: Could a BitSet be something - i.o. TreeSet? Requirement: not too wild numbers, and only non-negative ones. A BitSet is more compact, possibly faster.

Comment: "Those elements themselves need to be ordered but not necessarily sorted." - You should be using a `LinkedHashSet` for this instead, then.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `Those elements themselves need to be ordered but not necessarily sorted` - but they are **NOT** according to the data that you have provided yourself via `HashSet<....>`, as such this question is irrelevant IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to iterate over collection and convert inner sets into lists. Although if performance is of the greatest importance, consider using some third-party libraries, that provide some optimizations.

**1. Benchmarks**

I have written a couple of simple benchmarks using JMH to compare them with vanilla java solution:

```
public class Set2ListTest {

    private static final int SMALL_SET_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int LARGE_SET_SIZE = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(Set2ListTest.class.getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .threads(8)
                .warmupIterations(1)
                .measurementIterations(1)
                .build();
        new Runner(options).run();
    }

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class Provider {

        Set<Set<Integer>> smallSet = new HashSet<>(SMALL_SET_SIZE);
        Set<Set<Integer>> largeSet = new HashSet<>(LARGE_SET_SIZE);

        @Setup
        public void setup() {
            fillSet(smallSet, SMALL_SET_SIZE);
            fillSet(largeSet, LARGE_SET_SIZE);
        }

        private void fillSet(Set<Set<Integer>> set, int count) {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Set<Integer> innerSet = new TreeSet<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                    innerSet.add(random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                }
                set.add(innerSet);
            }
        }

    }

    @Benchmark
    public void small_plainJava(Provider provider, Blackhole blackhole) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(SMALL_SET_SIZE);
        for (Set<Integer> set : provider.smallSet) {
            list.add(new ArrayList<>(set));
        }
        blackhole.consume(list);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void large_plainJava(Provider provider, Blackhole blackhole) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(LARGE_SET_SIZE);
        for (Set<Integer> set : provider.largeSet) {
            list.add(new ArrayList<>(set));
        }
        blackhole.consume(list);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void small_guava(Provider provider, Blackhole blackhole) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(SMALL_SET_SIZE);
        for (Set<Integer> set : provider.smallSet) {
            list.add(com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(set));
        }
        blackhole.consume(list);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void large_guava(Provider provider, Blackhole blackhole) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(LARGE_SET_SIZE);
        for (Set<Integer> set : provider.largeSet) {
            list.add(com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(set));
        }
        blackhole.consume(list);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void small_commons(Provider provider, Blackhole blackhole) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(SMALL_SET_SIZE);
        for (Set<Integer> set : provider.smallSet) {
            List<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<>(SMALL_SET_SIZE);
            CollectionUtils.addAll(innerList, set);
            list.add(innerList);
        }
        blackhole.consume(list);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void large_commons(Provider provider, Blackhole blackhole) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(LARGE_SET_SIZE);
        for (Set<Integer> set : provider.largeSet) {
            List<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<>(LARGE_SET_SIZE);
            CollectionUtils.addAll(innerList, set);
            list.add(innerList);
        }
        blackhole.consume(list);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void small_eclipse(Provider provider, Blackhole blackhole) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = FastList.newList();
        for (Set<Integer> set : provider.smallSet) {
            list.add(FastList.newList(set));
        }
        blackhole.consume(list);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void large_eclipse(Provider provider, Blackhole blackhole) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = FastList.newList();
        for (Set<Integer> set : provider.largeSet) {
            list.add(FastList.newList(set));
        }
        blackhole.consume(list);
    }

}
```

**2. Results**

The results are as follows:

```
Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt        Score   Error  Units
Set2ListTest.large_commons    thrpt           183.205          ops/s
Set2ListTest.large_eclipse    thrpt           219.068          ops/s
Set2ListTest.large_guava      thrpt           178.478          ops/s
Set2ListTest.large_plainJava  thrpt           148.058          ops/s
Set2ListTest.small_commons    thrpt       2140560.198          ops/s
Set2ListTest.small_eclipse    thrpt       2619862.935          ops/s
Set2ListTest.small_guava      thrpt       2720692.868          ops/s
Set2ListTest.small_plainJava  thrpt       2472748.566          ops/s
```

**3. Discussion**

Two different sizes of `Set`s were used to measure performance: 10 sets of size 10 (100 elements) and 1000 sets of 1000 elements (1.000.000 elements).

For the small `Set`, eclipse collections outperformed the other tools. Plain java seems to be the slowest solution.

In the case of the larger `Set`, guava provides the best results.

It's obvious, that the size of collections has a great impact on performance and can influence the best choice among those libraries. I don't know the size of your data, but my goal is not to give you the best collections library but to give you a tool to find one.

**4. Additional notes**

I do not consider myself a specialist in any of the collection frameworks and there might be a better way to use them.

If those results are not satisfactory, you can use primitive collections, so that much less memory has to be allocated. This will result in a huge performance boost.

Note, that if you want to experiment with the benchmarks provided, it's important, that you compare the implementations against each other, not against the results I got, because that might be hardware-related.

Answer (score 4):

For the efficient way, you would have to test them using [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). I can give you the method of conversion, but they should perform as well:

You have plain old java loop, eg:

```
HashSet<TreeSet<Integer>> hash=new HashSet<TreeSet<Integer>>(); 
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(hash.size());
for (Set<Integer> a : hash) {
  list.add(new ArrayList<>(a));
}
```

This takes `O(n²)`.

And you have the one using `Stream`, which is also `O(n²)`:

```
hash.stream()
    .map(ArrayList::new)
    .collect(toList());
```

The difference in the second version is that you may eventually parallelize the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), using [`parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--): this is where you may gain performance (but you would still have to test using JMH).

Comment: You're just creating a List of Integers, not a List of Lists of Integers.  I assume that, instead of list.addAll you meant to put merely list.add.

Comment: That's for trying to write code without a compiler!